# Why is space not allocated before assignment for pointer variables that store the main's arguments that are to be used in the program?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, command-line-arguments, argv

I am writing a C program that requires me to take command-line arguments and use them in the program. What I don't understand is, why in the code, string arguments are assigned to a `char*` variable, for further use in program, when no memory is allocated before doing so. Isn't is necessary to allocate enough memory for a pointer to point to before using it?

```
//c program

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    //lets say there is only one argument after the program name 
    // so that argc = 2 and argv = {filename, string1}

    //assigning the string to a char *
    //no memory allocated before assignment
    char *x = argv[1];

    // rest of the program ...
}
```

Comment: If you want to **copy** the argument, then do allocate and use `strcpy()`: `char *x = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1) /* assume ok */; strcpy(x, argv[1]); /* rest of code */; free(x);`

Comment: Actually it's more like `argv = { filename, string1, NULL }`, it's guaranteed to be `NULL`-terminated which is very handy sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each item in `argv` already points to such allocated space, which was created by some C runtime support for storing the command-line arguments. You can therefore safely point to these pre-allocated buffers with your pointers.

Note that this also means you must not try to deallocate them either: whoever created them will be responsible for their correct destruction.